# VUEjs Array won't update after splice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Array only updates in console but not in DOM. I've already tried putting :key.
here's my code:

```
<div style="margin-top: 5px;" v-for="(file, index) in editedItem.file_name" 
                                         :key="editedItem.file_id[index]" >
    <a :href="`/biodidb/storage/${file}.${editedItem.file_type[index]}`" target="_blank">
        {{`${file}.${editedItem.file_type[index]}`}}
    </a>
    <span style="cursor: pointer;" @click="deleteData(editedItem.file_id[index], 'photos', index)">
        <v-icon
            small
            class="ml-3"
        >
           delete
        </v-icon>
        Delete 
    </span>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
deleteData(id, type, index) {
    this.editedItem.file_name.splice(index,1);
    this.editedItem.file_type.splice(index,1);
    this.editedItem.file_id.splice(index,1);
}
enter code here
```

I also have a method called update, and when clicked i'd assign an object to the object called editedItem in my data.

```
data() {
    return {
        editedItem: {}
    }
},
methods: {
      update(id, item) {
             this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item);
      }
}
```

Comment: Show your data function.

Comment: @zero298 my data is like this, 

return {
   editedItem: {},
}

i have a method called update, and when clicked i'd assign an object to the object called editedItem. 

update(id, item) {
   this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item);
}

Comment: Edit your question and put that in your question, not in the comments.

Comment: Define a placeholder for the array on the object in data. Vue cant track property creation on Objects.

Comment: @zero298 I think that's the solution. I did, made a new property called 'file_name' and defining it instead of making a new property worked

Answer (score 0):

How is your editedItem structure?? the way you are using the  v-for is for data like

```js
  data: {
    editedItem: {
      file_id: ['1'],
      file_type: ['type 1'],
      file_name: ['testing'],
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data looks like this:

```
...
data:function(){
    return{
        editedItem{}
    }
}
...
```

And afther that just add an array to an `editedItem` like this

```
editedItem.file_name = ['myFileName'];
```

then you new `file_name` property won't be reactive and won't be traced by Vue.

You need either specify the arrays you are going to use in `data` function:

```
    ...
        data:function(){
            return{
                editedItem:{
                    file_name:[]
                }
            }
        }
  ...
```

Or add new new property to editedItem by `Vue.set()`

```
Vue.set(editedItem,'file_name',['myFileName'];
```